# How can I know If a webcomponent is on screen in litelement?

Tags: web-component, polymer-2.x, google-web-component

Im doing a small proyect with litelement, but I want to fire an event when a webcomponent is shown, not only the first time, but every time that the component shows, how can I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Intersection Observer API** will help you find if the element is on the screen. For more information, [visit MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

```
// 1. Observer options
let options = {
  // The scroll area - mostly body or document
  root: document.querySelector('#parent'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
};

let callback = () => { /* Do something */ };

// Observe Element
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

// Start observing
const targetElm = document.querySelector('#target');
observer.observe(targetElm);
```

The API is supported on all browsers except IE but a polyfill is already available:
https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver